# List View Smooth Scroll to specific Position in Async Task is not working

Tags: android, json, listview, scroll

I Know this Question has been asked many many times before but mine problem is bit different.

I am working on a project in which I am getting `JSON` data from Webservice. In this app We can vote to different type of food items and list view will sort according the votes (Max Votes to Min Votes). On Vote Click on any list item the listview refresh and show the new sorted items list.

The `JSON` I am getting also provide me the index position of the item I vote in latest sort.

so Now I am getting the position of the voted item and I want to scroll it to that specific position after listview reload. I tried all methods provide over the internet but its not working for me.

Please Any Help Here is My code.

Here is My `RemoteDataTask` Async Class Code

```
public class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ItemRankActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading All Awesomeness of " + title);

        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog
                .setMessage("Wait.. While we Generating the Best Dishes for you.");
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                DishesArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < DishesArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = DishesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    arrayList.add(new ItemRankData(c.getString(TAG_PIC), c
                            .getString(TAG_TITLE), c
                            .getString(TAG_RESTAURANT), c
                            .getString(TAG_VOTES), c.getString(TAG_DISHID),
                            c.getString(TAG_FBID),
                            c.getString(TAG_IsVOTED), c
                                    .getString(TAG_IsTOP), c
                                    .getString(TAG_TopImage), c
                                    .getString(TAG_Position)));
                    if (c.getString(TAG_IsTOP).equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                        isTop = "yes";
                        Log.e("Is it on TOP", isTop);

                        if (c.getString(TAG_TopImage) != "") {
                            TopImageURL = c.getString(TAG_TopImage);
                            Log.e("Top image URL", TopImageURL);
                            VotedPosition = c.getString("position");
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.v("post", "After query post");

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(TopImageURL).into(img_item_image);
        PositionOfVote = Integer.parseInt(VotedPosition);
        lv_items_lists.smoothScrollToPosition(PositionOfVote);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ClassDataManager.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv_items_lists);
        Log.e("POST Execute Hit", "True");


        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

My Custom Adapter Class Code

```
public class ItemRankAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String URL;
JSONArray BestCatogryArray = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private ArrayList<ItemRankData> mlist;
private Context context;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private static String TAG_DATA = "data";
private static String TAG_VOTES = "votes";
JSONArray DishesArray = null;
String VOTES;
ViewHolder holder;
VOTING voting = new VOTING();
int POS;
public ItemRankAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ItemRankData> mlist) {
    this.context = c;
    this.mlist = mlist;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item_rank, parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_item_serialNo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_item_serialNo);
        holder.tv_item_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
        holder.tv_item_restaurant = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_item_restaurant);
        holder.tv_item_like_count = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_item_like_count);
        holder.img_logo = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
        holder.img_top_position = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_top_position);
        holder.ll_likes = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ll_likes);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final ItemRankData rankData = mlist.get(position);
    holder.tv_item_name.setText(rankData.itemName);
    holder.tv_item_restaurant.setText(rankData.itemRestaurantName);
    holder.tv_item_like_count.setText(rankData.itemLikes);
    Log.e("Position Value is " + position,
            " And The Name of Item Along with it is " + rankData.itemName);
    String imageUrl = rankData.itemRetaurantLogo;
    // imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, holder.img_logo);
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.img_logo);

    if (position == 0) {
        holder.tv_item_serialNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.img_top_position.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        holder.tv_item_serialNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.img_top_position.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        String s1 = String.format("%02d", (position + 1));
        holder.tv_item_serialNo.setText(s1);

    }
    if (rankData.isVoted.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        holder.ll_likes
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.top_selected_border);
        holder.tv_item_like_count.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.text_selected));
    } else {
        holder.ll_likes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_border);
        holder.tv_item_like_count.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.text_normal));

    }

    holder.ll_likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String dishId = rankData.dishId;
            URL = "http://Here I Write My URL?"
                    + "dishid="
                    + dishId
                    + "&"
                    + "fbid="
                    + PrefrencesClass.getStringPreference(context,
                            Constants.APPSPREF, Constants.USER_ID);
            new DataTask().execute();
            ((ItemRankActivity) context).UpdateRemoteDataRankActivity();
        }

    });

    return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_item_serialNo;
    TextView tv_item_name;
    TextView tv_item_restaurant;
    TextView tv_item_like_count;
    ImageView img_logo;
    LinearLayout ll_add;
    ImageView img_top_position;
    LinearLayout ll_likes;
    ImageView img_item_image;
}

//The Class to Send VOTE update URL to Server
private class DataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        return null;

    }

}}
```

Please Help me With it I am trying really hard from how and where can I solve this problem 
Any Help will be Great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
lv_items_lists.setSelection(PositionOfVote);
```

instead of

```
lv_items_lists.smoothScrollToPosition(PositionOfVote);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Try lv_items_lists.setSelection(PositionOfVote); directly without runnable

Comment: ` lv_items_lists.setSelection(PositionOfVote);`
Yes Its Working Fine on first call of `RemoteDataTask` but when I submit Vote and Again Call this Method then its not working.

Comment: then PositionOfVote value is not proper. try to find correct PositionOfVote value then it is working proper

Comment: Let me See and will tell you if any problem still happens

Comment: Thank you for your time I finally figured out the Issue

Answer (score 2):

```
lv_items_lists.setSelection(PositionOfVote);
```

try this after

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: its working same before and after of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

but only for first time

Comment: I guess something is wrong with the position please check weather its correct or not

Comment: I rechecked Everything is completely fine and getting the proper Position Before and after the update its totally fine.
same solution all over the internet but its not working for me 
can you please check the code if any issue in it ?

Comment: Yes this is working fine there was something else problem with my program :)

Comment: That's great buddy 
happy coding :-)